# template and p tag in the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/dhaileytaha/ghuj4jL8/7/ 
as in the above fiddle i need the p tag on the left hand side and the template on the right hand side at the same level

```
 <p>abcdefg</p>
 <!-- Offers List - START -->
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="listing listing-default">
            <div class="shape">
                <div class="shape-text">buy</div>
            </div>
            <div class="listing-content">
                <h3 class="lead">Standard listing</h3>
                <p>Buy items on normal prices. No discounts available for this listing.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<p>uvwzyx</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic is always

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-...">column1</div>
    <div class="col-...">column2</div>
    ...
</div>
```

12 columns represent the whole width.

[Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

The example has three columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md2">
      <p>abcdefg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="listing listing-default">
            <div class="shape">
                <div class="shape-text">buy</div>
            </div>
            <div class="listing-content">
                <h3 class="lead">Standard listing</h3>
                <p>Buy items on normal prices. No discounts available for this listing.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md2">
      <p>uvwzyx</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3btux56/1/)